# Reference request on Gentzen's proof of the consistency of PA

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy, proof-theory, foundations

I've always been interested in having a good understanding of Gentzen's proof of the consistency of arithmetic.

Being more precise, he showed that $PRA + WF(\epsilon_0) \vdash Con(PA)$.

I am interested in an exposition of his work that

**1)** Is transparent on which parts of the consistency proof uses the well-foundness of $\epsilon_0$.

**2)** Discuss (in mathematical and philosphical way) to what extent this proof deviate from the original Hilbert's Program, and in what extent it fits in a nice way to a more flexible formulation of this programme.

I should also add:

**0)** Is technically as simple as possible.

Item **0)** is because I think this question might be of interest to the curious general mathematician.

Comment: Not mainstream, but Chapter 3 of my 1980 thesis https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10540 gives an 8-page exposition of Ackermann, Dreben, Denton, and Scanlon's proof[s], recast using Kripke's notion of fulfillability.

Comment: @jeq Nice to learn that you thesis is now available on-line. Just recently I have mentioned it in my answer to this question  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365425/the-inconsistency-of-graham-arithmetics-plus-forall-n-n-g-64 .

Comment: Maybe useful: Anna Horská, [Where is the Gödel-point hiding: Gentzen's Consistency Proof of 1936 (Springer, 2014)](https://books.google.it/books?id=Iuq5BAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pohlers's 1989 book 'Proof Theory, An Introduction' gives a very clean, streamlined approach (based on work by Tait.)

Takeuti's presentation in his 'Proof Theory' is closer to Gentzen's original proof, but is much less readable than Pohlers.