# The Return of Graham Arithmetics: adding induction up to $g_{64}$

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, peano-arithmetic, ultrafinitism

In my previous question [The inconsistency of Graham Arithmetics plus $ \forall n, n < g_{64}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365425/the-inconsistency-of-graham-arithmetics-plus-forall-n-n-g-64), I introduced an extension of Robinson Arithmetics with the recursive definition of Tetraction, a small fragment of arithmetics which I have christened Graham (if someone comes up with a better name, please enter it in comments).

I have also added an axiom which makes it (in the conventional sense) inconsistent, by stipulating that Graham number is inaccessible. Thanks to the magnificient answers of Emil Jerabek and Fedor Pakhomov  I have a better idea  on how much it takes to prove efficiently  its inconsistency, and how.

Here, let us  remove the inaccessibility of Graham number, and add instead a **limited induction**. Not in the ordinary sense of fragments of arithmetic, which entails restricting the type of formulae for which induction is acceptable.

Rather, I want induction **UP TO**  $g_{64}$:given a formula $A(x)$

$ A(0)\land (A(x) \rightarrow \ A(Sx) \rightarrow \ \forall x (x<g_{64} \rightarrow \ A(x))$

So, here Graham number is inaccessible in the sense that induction  (without any restriction on A(x)) is limited to all terms which are below it.

Now my question:

Clearly Graham plus limited induction proves things which are provable in PA (it is a "straightjacketed" version of PA, if I may say so). But what else can PA prove about the finite initial segment of numbers below  $g_{64}$ beyond what the theory above already knows?

Or, assuming that PA proves something about the finite initial segment below Graham's number which is also known by Graham plus limited induction, can PA prove it more efficiently by benefiting from unbridled induction?

Comment: Let's try Graham Number Arithmetic, or GNumber Arithmetic for short.  Gerhard "I Pronounce It Guhnum Buhr" Paseman, 2020.07.25.

Comment: how about GI2, short for "Graham Is Inaccessible"?

Comment: The numeral two makes it confusing. If you must, go for GII.  Gerhard "Yes, Verbs Are Words Too"  Paseman, 2020.07.25.

Comment: Actually I like better your proposal: GNA shall be

Comment: Induction up to $g_{64}$ is *already* provable in Graham, thus the only effect of postulating it as an axiom schema is to shorten existing proofs.

Comment: Ok Emil, you are simply too smart for my little game. Yes, of course, for each single term below g(64) I can compute directly  what I get from my short induction. But, let us make it worthy of someone like you: can you give a precise sense of the impact of short induction? For instance, suppose I quickly establish A(0) and A(x) implies A(Sx), to leverage my induction schema for a given term t I still have to prove that t is below gl(64), so I have to do some extra work, right? Now, the question for you is, how much I get in making proofs shorter?